# ERROR: column "EP_TEXT" specified more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to use script to add column to table, no matter i change to which name, it always return error saying

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'xxx' in table
>   'TEST_TABLE' is specified more than once.

I randomly key in a name, it still saying that name is specified more than once. but actually not, there is no such column existed yet, and column finally is not added successfully also.

anyone had any idea? 
thanks

below is my query:

```
GO
if not exists(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'TEST_TABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'EP_TEXT')
begin 
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE ADD EP_TEXT [dbo].[UDDT_MAXVARCHAR] NULL
end 
GO
```

Comment: Include the schema in the `WHERE` clause: `... AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' ...`

Comment: its not working.

Comment: The problem is no matter i add with whichname, like "EP_TEXT_1","EP_TEXT_1_1", or even "sgadfkjehw3728", it still returns error saying column "sgadfkjehw3728" is specified more than 1 time

Comment: any idea about the possibel cause?

Comment: This is a compilation error, not an execution error. Your entire batch is compiled before execution and the existence of objects evaluated at that time. This is done statement by statement. Your code will "work" ONLY if the column you are adding does not exist when compiled. Once it exists, it generates the error despite the fact that your code will not attempt to add the column a second time. You need to use dynamic sql for this approach to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE does not have a COLUMN_NAME column. Try this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
     SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t1
              INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t2 on t1.TABLE_NAME = t2.TABLE_NAME
              where t1.TABLE_NAME = 'TEST_TABLE' and t2.COLUMN_NAME = 'EP_TEXT'
     )
```